# What is the better logic for identifying the latest versioned files from a big list

Tags: algorithm, sorting, comparison

I have 200 images in a folder and each file may contain several versions (example: car_image#2, car_image#2, bike_image#2, etc ). My requirement is to build a utility to copy all the latest files from this directory to another.

My approach is:

1. Put the imagesNames (without containing version numbers) into a list
2. Eliminate the duplicates from the list
3. Iterate through the list and identify the latest version of each unique file (I am little blurred on this step)
   Can someone throw some better ideas/algorithm to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be:

1. Make a list of unique names by getting each filename up to the `#`, only adding unique values.
2. Make a dictionary with filenames as keys, and set values to be the version number, updating when it's larger than the one stored.
3. Go through the dictionary and produce the filenames to grab.

My go-to would be a python script but you should be able to do this in pretty much whatever language you find suitable.

Ex code for getting the filename list:

```
#get the filename list
myList = []
for x in file_directory:
    fname = x.split("#")[0]
    if not fname in myList:
        myList = myList + [fname]
myDict = {}
for x in myList:
    if not x in myDict:
        myDict[x] = 0
for x in file_directory:
    fversion = x.split("#")[-1]
    if myDict[x] < int(fversion):
        myDict[x] = fversion
flist = []
for x in myDict:
    fname = str(x) + "#" + str(myDict[x])
    flist.append(fname)
```

Then `flist` would be a list of filenames of the most recent versions

I didn't run this or anything but hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3

```
>>> images = sorted(set(sum([['%s_image#%i' % (nm, random.randint(1,9)) for i in range(random.randint(2,5))] for nm in 'car bike cat dog man tree'.split()], [])))
>>> print('\n'.join(images))
bike_image#2
bike_image#3
bike_image#4
bike_image#5
car_image#2
car_image#7
cat_image#3
dog_image#2
dog_image#5
dog_image#9
man_image#1
man_image#2
man_image#4
man_image#6
man_image#7
tree_image#3
tree_image#4
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> image2max = defaultdict(int)
>>> for image in images:
    name, _, version = image.partition('#')
    version = int(version)
    if version > image2max[name]:
        image2max[name] = version


>>> # Max version
>>> for image in sorted(image2max):
    print('%s#%i' % (image, image2max[image]))


bike_image#5
car_image#7
cat_image#3
dog_image#9
man_image#7
tree_image#4
>>>
```